# Jenkins and Zephyr integration for Protractor Tests

Tags: git, jenkins, svn, jira, jira-zephyr

We are trying to integrate Jira and jenkins . We are using Zephyr for test management, and for Jenkins integration, we already installed the Zapi. In Jenkins the Zephyr plug in is installed. so far Jenkins can connect with Jira and shows us the projects. We are following the steps described [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Zephyr+For+Jira+Test+Management+Plugin) , but this guideline tells us to have a Subversion Repository. Currently our project is residing in Git and we want to keep it this way.

For testing purpose, I have put the project on a local folder. in the project config, I added both "Publish test result to Zephyr for JIRA" and "Publish JUnit test result report" as Post build actions.

When we run the tests, we see the test are running fine in Jenkins, but it fails to create test cases in Jira and also fails to create xml reports. The relevant log is as follows:

> Report successfully generated to C:\Users\\Desktop\Project\allure-report
>   Allure report was successfully generated.
>   Creating artifact for the build.
>   Artifact was added to the build.
>   Recording test results
>   ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did leafNodes run? 
>   For example, C:\Users\\Desktop\Project\XMLRepo\a.xml is 10 min old
>
> [ZapiTestResultReporter] [INFO] Examining test results... Build result
>   is FAILURE null Problem parsing JUnit test Results. Error parsing
>   surefire reports. Please ensure "Publish JUnit test result report is
>   added" as a post build action Build step 'Publish test result to
>   Zephyr for JIRA' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

Questions:

1. Do we really need to use Subversion Services for these integration?
2. If this integration can be done using GIT, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

We finally found out that we do not need Subversion. The Git repo works just fine. In the project configuration add the Git repo as the source and that's it.